# infopath 2010 column display help information

Tags: infopath

I am using Infopath form for a sharepoint 2010 list. I want to display a help text(which is of 10 lines) near to the column.

Like ? button and when the user clicks it show the information..

How can achieve this in Infopath

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could handle this with a collapsible section. You need a section, a toggle variable and two buttons.

Add a section next or under your entry field and paste your text into this section control.
Add a field (*Add Field*) and name it *toggleVariable*. Default value shall be 'off'.

Now add two buttons (change their label to 3 and 6 in font Marlett to get the characteristic look) and add rules to both buttons. Select *set a field's value* for button click and set *toggleVariable* to *on* respectively *off*.

After that set a rule for your section. Add Rules -> Formatting -> Hide this control on toggleVariable = Off. You can do the same for the buttons, so that only one button is displayed at a time, depending on the value of your toggleVariable.

Check out this website for more information: http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2012/04/23/how-to-create-expandable-collapsable-sections-in-infopath-aspx/

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. Your solution is almost what i need but i need the information to be popup ? .. How can do this or is it possible ?

Comment: I do not know of any possibility. There seems to be an action "Show a message", but this is not available for me: https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Add-rules-for-performing-other-actions-5322d726-b787-4e5f-8d37-ba6db68b451d